# Reset jQuery animation when it stops animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an amazing ripple effect implementation from this [website](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/recreating-the-touch-ripple-effect-as-seen-on-google-design--cms-21655) that uses the SVG/Circle element and a jQuery animation function to create the ripple effect on user-click. Although I have a knowledge of basic programming, I know less about JavaScript and jQuery methods/functions so I did read a lot from my research about JS and jQuery.

I found the ripple effect implementation; useful, light-weight and easy so I want to explore and expand the code to fit onto my projects.

Okay, so the first thing I need to know here is, how can I reset the changes made by the animation when it stops animating? I know this is a simple question for you but as a beginner at JS and jQuery, how can I achive that?

Here's the demo [code](http://jsbin.com/locemepepu/edit?js,output) to see what is actually happening here.

I tried adding the function (as seen on the code):

```
complete : function(){c.removeAttr('style');}
```

But nothing has changed and it still remains after the animation ends.

Any idea what I'm missin'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change complete callback to:

```
complete : function() { $(this).remove(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove "r" from the style attribute of the circle, try

```
complete : function(){c.css( "r", "" );}
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/css/ Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" )` — removes that property from an element.

or

```
complete : function(){c.css( "r", "0" );}
```

Try running the snippet below:

```js
(function(){
  
    $(".button").on("click", function(e){

        var yOffset = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        var xOffset = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        var self = this;
            
        var xPos = parseInt(xOffset);
        var yPos = parseInt(yOffset);

        $(this).find("svg").remove(); // Remove existing animation changes
        $(this).append('<svg><circle cx="'+xPos+'" cy="'+yPos+'" r="'+0+'"></circle></svg>');
            

        /* Make the animation of SVG - Circle */
        var c = $(self).find("circle");
        c.animate(
            {
                "r" : $(self).outerWidth()
            },
            {
                easing: "easeOutQuad",
                duration: 500,
                step : function(val){},

                /*-------------------------
                 THIS FUNCTION SHOULD WORK
                --------------------------*/
                complete : function(){c.css( "r", "0" );}
            }
        );
    });
}());
```

```css
.button {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 20px;
margin: 0;
background: transparent;
border: none;
color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 900;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: rgba(158,158,158,0.10);
}

.button:active,
.button:focus {
background-color: rgba(158,158,158, 0.30);
outline: 0;
}


/* SVG - Circle for the ripple effect */
.button svg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.button circle {
fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Reset jQuery animation when it stops animating</title>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button">Button</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ChainTrap I see, it doesn't work on JSBin with `complete : function(){c.css( "r", "" );}`, I have edited my answer, the callback should be `complete : function(){c.css( "r", 0 );}`

Comment: according to the jquery's documentation (http://api.jquery.com/css/) `e.g. $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" )` — removes that property from an element ` obviously it doesn't work on JSBin.

Comment: @ChainTrap did you try `complete : function(){c.css( "r", "0" );}` ?

Comment: Yes the — complete : function(){c.css("r","0");} function doesn't work on my editor and in JS Bin.

Comment: There must be some syntax error in your case, but It does work on JS Bin, see http://jsbin.com/qamihefuwi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You should use stop method for animation stop -
https://api.jquery.com/stop/

you can also use clearQueue method

Comment: Could you share the code so I can see where to place the function at my code?

Comment: instead of c.removeAttr('style'); use this $(this).remove();